# Baseball, when was the third strike rule put into effect when bunting?

Tags: baseball

Baseball, when was the third strike on bunting put into effect?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [list](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/rulechng.shtml) of MLB Rule Changes, bunts started counting as strikes in 1894.  A foul bunt that is not caught in flight is always counted as a strike, even if it is a third strike.

> 1894:
>       Foul bunts were classified as strikes.